# IronPython: convert C# List to IronPython.Runtime.List

Tags: python, c#, arrays, scripting, ironpython

I'm trying to send an array/list to an IronPython method as argument.

I can pass a normal array or list (and it works), but then native methods like `pop` are not available on the Python side.

What is the best way to convert a C# `List<>` to an `IronPython.Runtime.List`?

I found the `IronPython.Runtime.List.__new__` method but I don't know how to fill `CodeContext` and `PythonType` variables.

I found this for the other way around: [passing Lists from IronPython to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209675/passing-lists-from-ironpython-to-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops - found it. Just using an empty constructor():

```
public static IronPython.Runtime.List ToPythonList(this IEnumerable<object> list)
{
    var result = new IronPython.Runtime.List();

    foreach ( var item in list )
        result.append( item );

    return result;
}
```